# Calippo, toothpaste and milk .. packing

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, surfaces

[This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1981695/what-shape-is-a-calippo) was posing the question "The Calippo™ popsicle has a specific shape ... Does this shape have an official name?", and the accepted answer was that it is a [*Right Conoid*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conoid) which in fact is much resembling.

However,  a conoid is **not developable** and so cannot be economically made out of a cardboard sheet.

Now, a cardboard cylinder, pinched and sealed at one end, will look like a toothpaste tube, and the
pinched end will  be larger than the mouth diameter (by $\pi /2 $).
That does not fit to the calippo's look, 
whose tube is in fact fabricated from a cone (made from a plane circular sector) pinched at one end (and reinforced at the opposite circular rim).

And a related subject is that,  a cylinder with both ends  pinched at  90° relative to each other make up 
a tetrahedral "milk carton" (berlingot in French).
In this [Mathcurve page](http://www.mathcurve.com/surfaces/berlingot/berlingot.shtml)  after stating that
"le berlingot est la surface réglée non développable .. ",
referring to a picture of a real tetrahedral milk carton is noted:
"Attention, un berlingot comme ci-dessus fabriqué avec du papier 
est une surface développable, fabriquée avec un patron de tétraèdre en arrondissant les arêtes... "
Also refer to the [Coin Conic](http://www.mathcurve.com/surfaces/coinconic/coinconic.shtml) page.

Suppose that the material is inextensible, and that a grid of directrices and orthogonal circles is marked on the cone/cylinder,
then it is clear that upon pinching the directrices will not appear straight. 
Since a developable surface implies that it be ruled, then either the ruling lines have moved, or the surface has undergone some deformation.
Therefore the question is:

Can the calippo (and bottom of toothpaste, and milk) package be a ruled **developable** surface , in case, admitting that the shape of the pinched edge be not exactly linear ?
or is some deformation of the material demanded ?

**---- P.S:  -----**

Thanks to the answer, with expressive sketch, received by *Rahul*, complemented with that provided by *C.Blatter* to [the previous post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1981695/what-shape-is-a-calippo), we can conclude that such a surface is a plausible model.
So, scaling all the dimensions to have the base circle of radius $1$, height $=h$ and length of the pitch $=2c$

[image: calippo3]

we can parametrise the surface as
$$
\eqalign{
  & {\bf q} = \left( {sc,\;0,h} \right) - \left( {\cos \alpha ,\;\sin \alpha ,0} \right) = \left( {sc - \cos \alpha ,\; - \sin \alpha ,h} \right)  \cr 
  & {\bf p} = \left( {\cos \alpha ,\;\sin \alpha ,0} \right) + t\,{\bf q} \cr} 
$$
where
$$
\left\{ \matrix{
  \alpha  =  - \pi /2\quad  - 1 < s < 1\quad 0 \le t \le 1 \hfill \cr 
   - \pi /2 < \alpha  < \pi /2\quad s = 1\quad 0 \le t \le 1 \hfill \cr 
  \alpha  = \pi /2\quad  - 1 <  - s < 1\quad 0 \le t \le 1 \hfill \cr 
  \pi /2 < \alpha  < 3\pi /2\quad s =  - 1\quad 0 \le t \le 1 \hfill \cr}  \right.
$$

Then we can develop half of the surface as indicated, by putting for the flattened conic part that
$$
q(\alpha )d\beta (\alpha ) = d\alpha \quad \left| \matrix{
  \,q = \left| {\bf q} \right| \hfill \cr 
  \,s = 1 \hfill \cr}  \right.
$$

Comment: The other suggestion in that question, the convex hull of a line segment and a circle, *is* a developable surface. Does that answer your question?

Comment: On the other hand the tetrahedral milk carton will actually form exactly a tetrahedron with four flat triangular faces.

Comment: @Rahul what do you mean by *convex hull* ? made by straight lines ? if so, how do you relate (map)  the end points $P(s)$ on the segment with $Q(r \alpha)$ on the circle? under a linear map I am not sure it will be developpable. That's the core of the question.

Comment: @Rahul One matter is to make up a tetrahedron by taking a piece of paper, draw the four triangles connected on a hedge, fold it and solder on three edges. Another is to start from a cylinder, pinch and solder it at the ends, making them more or less straight, in case trimming straight the joints. Just think and cut open a milk carton ..

Comment: Careful: the curved sections do not unfold to sectors of a circle, because they are not portions of *right* circular cones. After all the three angles at the apex of each isosceles triangle should add up to $180^\circ$.

Comment: oohps, you are .."right" ! the half cones are not *right* : their median generatrix is (if the pinch equals the diameter). But I do not get your remark about the triangles.

Comment: I mean there should not be two "corners" where the arcs meet; they should form a single differentiable contour. After all if you look at the two sliver triangles on both sides of the large one in my discretized figure, all three are almost coplanar, and *their* angles at the shared vertex add up to almost $180^\circ$. In the limit this tells you something about the angle between the contour's tangents on either side.

Comment: A better approximation might be a single circular arc centered at roughly $(0,-2)$ in your figure.

Comment: @Rahul: so I re-elaborated the situation and edited the P.S., and in fact the sector is almost circular (for $h>>c$ )

Answer (score 1):

The convex hull of a circle and a line segment is developable. I don't know if this is the unique developable surface with the given boundaries.

[image]

(Ignore the extra chords drawn in the circle.)

I'm fairly sure that if you start with a cylinder and pinch it flat at both ends, a perfectly flat tetrahedron is the only developable surface you can get. The curved nature of the real-world milk cartons is because the material is slightly extensible (it has a coating of plastic to make it liquid-proof). Better intuition can be gained by trying the experiment with a sheet of plain paper instead.

Comment: this solid, with the right proportions chosen, can cast a shadow of a circle, a square, or an equilateral triangle. From a book I read as a child.

Comment: @WillJagy: Usually people have [a slightly different shape](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1947378/856) in mind for that problem, though this one works too. However I think it is impossible to have a circle, a square, and an *equilateral* triangle as shadows, because the altitude of the triangle is too short.

Comment: I guess you are right, if you tilt it just a little you get an elliptical arc as part of the shadow.