# Surface equation between two curves

Tags: geometry, surfaces, curves

I am faced to a problem where I need to get the parametric equation of the surface generated by 2 curves.

For example, I have the equation of a circle $(x, y, z) = (R\cos(t), R\sin(t), 0)$ and the equation of a line. I want to get the surface between them to have a special cylinder like the photo below :

[Special cylinder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GKF0n.jpg)

Is it possible to compute the parametric equation of this surface ?

Thanks

Comment: It is conoid surface. Have a look to (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1985163/calippo-toothpaste-and-milk-packing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

[image]

\begin{align} 
L=6\,R
,\\
S(u,v)&=
(R\cos u,\, R\,(1-\tfrac{v}L)\sin u,\,v)
,\quad u\in[0,2\pi],\ v\in[0,L]
.
\end{align}