# Cutting cork for three different holes

Tags: calculus, euclidean-geometry

A cork of circular base, radius 1 unit and height of 2 units can be carved to snugly fit into square, circular and triangular holes. What is the volume of the smallest shape that can fit and what is the volume of the largest shape? I don't know how to calculate these volumes either with pre-calculus or calculus methods.

Comment: Isn't the minimun (or rather infimum) volume just zero?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1947363

Comment: What does the "... shape that can fit" fit?

Comment: It wouldn't be a cork then!